# Blazor Hybrid DataGrid - How to not have to declare TRowData on every column

Tags: blazor, maui-blazor

Original source of the project....
https://www.meziantou.net/creating-a-datagrid-component-in-blazor.htm

Consider this datagrid below. I will post the full code after the brief description of my aim. A small amount of the original code is temporarily thinned out only to try and focus on the question at hand.

For brevity, I wish to move from declaring the TRowData on every column...

```
<GGrid2 Items="salesRecords">
    <GCol2 TRowData="SalesRecord" Expression="c => c.Category" />
    <GCol2 TRowData="SalesRecord" Expression="c => c.Product" />
    <GCol2 TRowData="SalesRecord" Expression="c => c.Sales" />
</GGrid2>
```

To only declaring it once at the level of the outer GGrid2 component markup.

```
<GGrid2 TRowData="SalesRecord" Items="salesRecords">
    <GCol2 Expression="c => c.Category" />
    <GCol2 Expression="c => c.Product" />
    <GCol2 Expression="c => c.Sales" />
</GGrid2>
```

How can I alter my code to acheive this? The fuller code as it currently works is below.

The markup the user uses, along with some sample data.

```
<GGrid2 Items="salesRecords">
    <GCol2 TRowData="SalesRecord" Expression="c => c.Category" />
    <GCol2 TRowData="SalesRecord" Expression="c => c.Product" />
    <GCol2 TRowData="SalesRecord" Expression="c => c.Sales" />
</GGrid2>

@code {
    private List<SalesRecord> salesRecords = new List<SalesRecord>
    {
        new SalesRecord { Category = "Electronics", Product = "Television", Sales = 1000.50m },
        new SalesRecord { Category = "Electronics", Product = "Cell Phone", Sales = 500.25m },
        new SalesRecord { Category = "Clothing", Product = "T-Shirt", Sales = 25.00m },
        new SalesRecord { Category = "Clothing", Product = "Jeans", Sales = 50.00m },
        new SalesRecord { Category = "Clothing", Product = "Jacket", Sales = 100.00m },
        new SalesRecord { Category = "Furniture", Product = "Sofa", Sales = 250.75m },
        new SalesRecord { Category = "Furniture", Product = "Chair", Sales = 50.15m },
        new SalesRecord { Category = "Furniture", Product = "Table", Sales = 150.25m }
    };

    private class SalesRecord
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public decimal Sales { get; set; }
    }
```

GGrid2.razor...

```
@typeparam TRowData
<CascadingValue IsFixed="true" Value="this">@ChildContent</CascadingValue>

<ggrid>
    <table @attributes="@TableAttributes">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var column in columns)
                {
                    @column.HeaderTemplate
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                if (Items != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Items)
                    {
                        <tr>
                        @foreach (var column in columns)
                        {
                            @column.CellTemplate(item)
                        }                        
                        </tr>                        
                    }
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</ggrid>

@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> TableAttributes { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ICollection<TRowData> Items { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Func<TRowData, int, string> RowClass { get; set; }

    private readonly List<GCol2<TRowData>> columns = new List<GCol2<TRowData>>();

    internal void AddColumn(GCol2<TRowData> column)
    {
        columns.Add(column);
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

GCol2.razor

```
@typeparam TRowData
@using System.Linq.Expressions

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public GGrid2<TRowData> OwnerGrid { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Expression<Func<TRowData, object>> Expression { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Format { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<TRowData> ChildContent { get; set; }

    private Func<TRowData, object> compiledExpression;
    private Expression lastCompiledExpression;
    private RenderFragment headerTemplate;
    private RenderFragment<TRowData> cellTemplate;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        OwnerGrid.AddColumn(this);
    }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (lastCompiledExpression != Expression)
        {
            compiledExpression = Expression?.Compile();
            lastCompiledExpression = Expression;
        }
    }

    internal RenderFragment HeaderTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return headerTemplate ??= (builder =>
            {
                // Use the provided title or infer it from the expression
                var title = Title;
                if (title == null && Expression != null)
                {
                    title = GetMemberName(Expression);
                }

                builder.OpenElement(0, "th");
                builder.AddContent(1, title);
                builder.CloseElement();
            });
        }
    }

    internal RenderFragment<TRowData> CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return cellTemplate ??= (rowData => builder =>
            {
                builder.OpenElement(0, "td");
                if (compiledExpression != null)
                {
                    var value = compiledExpression(rowData);
                    var formattedValue = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Format) ? value?.ToString() : string.Format("${0:" + Format + "}", value);
                    builder.AddContent(1, formattedValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    builder.AddContent(2, ChildContent, rowData);
                }

                builder.CloseElement();
            });
        }
    }

    private static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<T> expression)
    {
        return expression.Body switch
        {
            MemberExpression m => m.Member.Name,
            UnaryExpression u when u.Operand is MemberExpression m => m.Member.Name,
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException("Expression of type '" + expression.GetType().ToString() + "' is not supported")
        };
    }
}
```

The grid working below...

[image]

Comment: Seems to me, that the answer to this lay in the use of the CascadingValue area. I'm convinced it can be done, but have yet to develop a btter understanding of cascading

Comment: No it's not.  You need to know what `TRowData` is to construct the object instance, as in for instance the property `Expression<Func<TRowData, object>>`.  Parameters are "injected" through reflection by the `Renderer` post class `Ctor` and before calling `Attach` on the component.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I not declare TRowData on every column...

I don't think you can: you can't pass a generic as a Parameter.  I've searched long and hard through all sorts of implementations of grids and similar components to see if anyone has a devious solution.

Comment: An observation: you're cascading the top level grid component.  I cascade  a `ListContext` object: similar concept to the `EditContext` .  It's the "operations centre" for the list form.  It manages state, sorting and paging, drives rendering through events and can be persisted to maintain state across page changes.

Comment: Seems to me, that the answer to this lay in the use of the CascadingValue area. I'm convinced it can be done, but have yet to develop a btter understanding of cascading.